# Access Form having Write Conflict issue when checking a checkbox in a form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have an Access form where users can add new phone numbers for a client. So the form works in the following ways:

1. There is a main form called **Update Client Details** which contains a subform called **Update Phone** which shows the list of phone numbers the Client has. Following are the fields in the form:

```
[cID][FullName][PhoneType][PhoneNumber][Active]
1     Test ter   Mobile     0899955522    []<=(blank check box)
```

2. There is an **Update** button on the form that opens a new form where users can add a new phone number for the client.
3. When the user adds a new phone number, the phone number is displayed in the **Update Phone subform** with Active being 0 by default (Active is a checkbox field).
4. Whenever I click the checkbox to make the phone number active I receive the write conflict error.

Please find the attached image:

[image: WriteConflict]

I'm the only user currently working on the database. Can someone please help me solve the issue? Thank you all in advance.

[image: UpdatePhoneSubform]

[image: AddNewPhoneNumber]

[image: Back to Update Client Details form where new number is shown in Update Phone subform]

[image: Wherever trying to check the checkbox it's giving the write conflict error]

Comment: Save the record before checking the checkbox.

Comment: Record has been placed into Edit mode by code then you try to manually edit. Those are the user conflicts. Why would you need to pop up a form for entering new record as opposed to just entering on subform? Just put user focus on new record row. Why would phone list table/form have FullName field?

Comment: @Gustav Thanks very much for your reply. The record is already saved, right? Also, find the visuals of the form that I have attached recently.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate a bit more on where you have mentioned edit mode by code and then trying to manually edit. I have created a new popup form to enter a new record as it's more user-friendly and they can see the overview of records in the main form.  Please find the visuals of the form that I have attached recently. Thanks once again.

Comment: Somewhere somehow, record edit is initiated with some code then you attempt to manually edit the same record (or vice versa). I encountered this once early in my db programming experience. Was quite frustrating until I tracked down the code causing this and revised.

Comment: @June7 Thanks and sorry for the late reply. Actually, the write conflict issue is only occurring when keeping the "Active" field in the query which is a checkbox field. As soon as I remove the "Active" field from the query, there is no more write conflict occurring. Would you know why this is happening? Thanks a million.

Comment: While debugging this, it is very helpful to turn on the Record Selector on both the form and subform. Then you will see when/if the record is edited.

Comment: Without examining db structure, form design, code, no way for me to determine cause. Might post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: @Andre Thanks for your reply. I was able to remove the write conflict by making the default value of the record selector 1. Now it's not showing the Write conflict anymore. I don't know why it was having the write conflict issue when the default value was 0. Strange

Comment: @June7 Thanks for your reply. I was able to remove the write conflict by making the default value of the record selector 1. Would you know why did this happen?

Comment: Ok, that is ... unexpected. :)

Comment: Just how do you set a default value of a record selector? This really does not make sense.

Comment: @Andre Ikr :). I'm confused as well.

Comment: @June7 By adding the record selector field in the form and making the field's default value 1. Now by default when the user enters a new record and saves it the default value of the record selector would be set as 1. :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'record selector field' - a field used to flag a record for some filter purpose? Is this a multi-user split db? Users can conflict with each other. You may have eliminated the error with setting a default value but still does explain why this error was occurring in the first place.

Comment: @June7 Record Selector Field is basically the checkbox field as referred by Andre in the comments. Yes, the DB is a multi-user split DB but at the moment I was the only one working with the DB. Yes, I agree that the error is eliminated by setting a default value to the field but I would like someone to explain to me why is this an issue!

Answer (score 0):

write conflict happen when two users open same table exclusively , when you click update your table is a `record source` for the two forms.

solution:

1- Make clients list `Form` `Record Source` as Query not Table.

2- make the client relation's phone update `Form` to  `Unbounded Form` with un bounded controls

and use following code to perform update when you click `Save and Close`

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Your Table Name ] " & _
"SET [Client Phone Field] ='" & [Phone Number Text Box] & "' " & _
"WHERE [Client ID Field ] = '" & [Your Client ID Text Box] "'"
```